# Using block or NSOperation for loading Image?

Tags: ios, multithreading, objective-c-blocks, nsoperation, grand-central-dispatch

I need to know if it's better to use NSOperation or Block to load a large number of image into a UIScrollView? I create all the Imageview and positioning each UIImageView in the right position into the scroll.

To avoid memory warning I choose to load the image once at time. My idea is to create a sort of queue and insert all the image to load in the queue. I have to use block or NSOperation to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you can use GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) to load the images asynchronously.

Like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
NSString *imagepath = //get path to image here
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[cell imageView] setImage:image];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    });
});
return cell;
```

---

Edit: For a better answer, watch WWDC '12 Session 211 - "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS" (thanks @sc0rp10n!)

Comment: Someone down-voted with no explanation.  If you happen to see this, mind explaining what wrong with this answer?

Comment: what happens if you scroll up and down and the rows go on and off the screen?  Using this method won't the wrong images appear at first only to be replaced eventually with the proper image? (I didn't down vote FYI)

Comment: No, not if you create the image path that links to the correct image, based off of the index path.

Comment: This solution is wrong. The cell that will receive the image asynchronously might have been recycled during that period of time (or even released). You should take a look for example at AFNetworking (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) and the UIImageView+AFNetworking category.

Comment: @Martin: I answered this before `AFNetworking` even existed. Definitely that's a better way to go.

Comment: For a new way to implement this in iOS 6, see the new WWDC2012 Video: Session 211 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS. This demonstrates correctly canceling the image load on recycled cells (roughly 38:00 - 45:00).

Comment: Thanks @sc0rp10n, I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a queue then NSOperationQueue (and therefore NSOperations) is a sensible thing to use :)

Comment: what is the main difference instead of using the GDC and blocks?

Comment: Almost certainly none - I bet NSOperation uses GCD under the hood. I just find working with NSOperations easier :)

Comment: I can add th image to the superview inside the NSOperation object??

Comment: Probably not, no - an NSOperation runs on a background thread. however, you can use something like `[myView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:imageView waitUntilDone:YES];` to make sure that it happens on the main thread.